# Check if transaction on a innoDB row is occurring?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

If a database transaction is occurring on one thread is there a way for other threads to check to see if this transaction is already occurring before attempting the transaction? I know innoDB has row-level locking but I want the transaction to not be attempted if its already occurring on another thread, instead of waiting for the lock to be released and then attempting it.

To make my question clearer, an explanation of what I am trying to do may help:

I am creating a simple raffle using php and a innoDB table with MySQL. When a user loads the page to view the raffle it checks the raffle's database row to see if its scheduled end time has passed and if its "processed" column in the database is true or false.

If the raffle needs to be processed it will begin a database transaction which takes about 5 seconds before being committed and marked as "processed" in the database.
 If multiple users load the page at around the same time I feel that it will process the raffle more than once which is not what I want. Ideally it would only attempt to process the raffle if no other threads are processing it, otherwise it would do nothing.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement table level locking and handle any subsequent connections to either be run in a queue or fail quietly:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

From the MySQL docs:

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```